# Time machine moving files from .Trashes

Tags: macos, osx-lion, time-machine

My HDD on my laptop (MBP 13) running Lion decided to suddenly die.

Just before it did, my intelligent self was deleting files from my external HDD where TimeMachine was doing backups. My reason for deleting files was that I had 3 backups accumulated and decided to bin 2 and leave the most recent one to use the portable HDD to transfer some stuff.

Because the laptop crapped out whilst performing a backup, it left me with a file called

`2011-10-26-235940.inProgress`

The older backups I deleted (from the external HDD) were in the trash, but never got to empty it, so no they are in a hidden folder called .Trashes within the external HDD.

Bought a new HDD, installed Snow Leopard, and all from scratch.

Copied the files from the `.trashed` folder to my new and fresh OSX. Problem? all files are locked. I mean, everyting!. Pictures, Documents, .... the lot. I assume is for security purposes.

I tried using time machine but it tells me there are no backups available on the HDD.

MY question to you out there is:

1. Can I move the file from `.trashes` back on to the Backups.Backupdb folder in my external HDD? (because when I try it tells me `Backups.Backupdb` cant be modified). That way I can use time machine or migration assistance to pull back the files i need without authentication issues.
2. Or is there a way to unlock all the files in my new OSX install?. I tried doing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> then clicking on the lock icon at the very bottom, entering my password, and it unlocks, but as soon as I get info again, it appears locked again!.

Any ideas, suggestions, or anything will help, and I'll even buy you a beer if you are in my town, because I am going mad here